# Can I use the conditional ternary operator into a string concatenation?

Tags: java, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I have the following doubt: can I in some way use the **conditional ternary operator** into a string concatenation?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
String sql = "insert into TirConsolidatoPolizzaFondo "
                       + "(Polizzaid, FondoID, isQuadraturaOk, ReteVendita,  CodiceConferimento, PercentualeRendimentoDaInizioGestione, "
                       + "DataInizioGestione, PercentualeRendimentoDaInizioAnno, DataInizioAnno, PercentualeRendimentoDaInizioTrimestre, "
                       + "DataInizioTrimestre, DataCalcoloBF, ValoreNavBF, DataRiferimentoNavBF, ControvaloreFinaleBF, ValoreNavPUC, "
                       + "DataRiferimentoNavPUC, ControvaloreFinalePUC, NumeroQuotePUC, DeltaControvaloreFinale, TIMESTAMP, "
                       + "DataValutaUltimaOperazione, MsgPercentualeRendimentoDaInizioAnno, MsgPercentualeRendimentoDaInizioGestione, "
                       + "MsgPercentualeRendimentoDaInizioTrimestre, isTirAnomalo, CodiceLineaBF) "
                       + "values"
                       + "(" + 



                       qsTirPF.getPolizzaid() != null ?  qsTirPF.getPolizzaid() : "null";
```

that means that at the first String trunk I want to concatenate the value evaluated by:

```
qsTirPF.getPolizzaid() != null ?  qsTirPF.getPolizzaid() : "null";
```

but Eclipse sign me this error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object&Comparable<?>&Serializable to String
```

Why? What is wrong? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried putting parentheses around the ternary expression? `... + (qsTirPF.getPolizzaid() != null ?  qsTirPF.getPolizzaid() : "null");`

Comment: Also are you sure you want to use string concatenation to provide SQL query arguments? Usually preferred way to avoid Bobby Tables is to  use PreparedStatement and use its `setXYZ` methods.

Comment: As a note, this is 2016; do yourself a favor and use prepared statements to avoid potential SQL injections.

Comment: Anyway I can't reproduce this exact problem. Could you post proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE] which will allow us to simply copy your example to our IDEs and to get same error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you should put your ternary condition inside brackets :

```
(qsTirPF.getPolizzaid() != null ?  qsTirPF.getPolizzaid() : "null")
```

Furthermore you should verify that qsTirPF.getPolizzaid() is returning a string

Comment: qsTirPF.getPolizzaid() can be whatever he wants. If it's an object (not a primitive), the toString() will be called.

Comment: Yes. I just tell him to verify what it is returning. He could have an error in the toString() if he overide it. But normaly he just need the brackets

Answer (score 3):

You need brackets:

```
String sql = "insert into TirConsolidatoPolizzaFondo "
    + "(Polizzaid, FondoID, isQuadraturaOk, ReteVendita,  CodiceConferimento, PercentualeRendimentoDaInizioGestione, "
    + "DataInizioGestione, PercentualeRendimentoDaInizioAnno, DataInizioAnno, PercentualeRendimentoDaInizioTrimestre, "
    + "DataInizioTrimestre, DataCalcoloBF, ValoreNavBF, DataRiferimentoNavBF, ControvaloreFinaleBF, ValoreNavPUC, "
    + "DataRiferimentoNavPUC, ControvaloreFinalePUC, NumeroQuotePUC, DeltaControvaloreFinale, TIMESTAMP, "
    + "DataValutaUltimaOperazione, MsgPercentualeRendimentoDaInizioAnno, MsgPercentualeRendimentoDaInizioGestione, "
    + "MsgPercentualeRendimentoDaInizioTrimestre, isTirAnomalo, CodiceLineaBF) "
    + "values"
    + "(" + (qsTirPF.getPolizzaid() != null ?  qsTirPF.getPolizzaid() : "null");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use parenthesis to tell the compiler that you want to concatenate with the result of your conditional ternary operator :

```
String sql = "insert into TirConsolidatoPolizzaFondo "
                   + ...
                   + ((getPolizzaid() != null)?  qsTirPF.getPolizzaid() : "null");
```

This should work.

PS : You can use a StringBuilder to build your query instead of using + sign. It's more efficient.

Comment: The Java compiler will turn this into code using a StringBuilder, anyhow. If you disassemble the class file, you'll see that.

Comment: It is the case, when all the strings are static. I can't be sure, the compiler would optimize this code when there is a conditional concatenation.

Comment: This si not ever true, for example the statemant: 
"bla bla bla "  + this.myList == null ? "null" : this.myList.size(); 
is a valid sentence, no compile error